# Getting date format in xslt

Tags: xslt

I have a xslt code for getting date.my code is like

```
<xsl:copy-of select="substring-before(msxsl:node-set($notes)/root/item/LASTCHANGED,'T')"/>
```

her I got Output Like 2013-04-05

but I need to get Output Like  15 jan 2013.

How can I achive this?any one help

Comment: You've tagged the question xslt-2.0 but you're using `msxsl:node-set` which (a) isn't needed in xslt 2 and (b) suggests you're using the msxsl processor, which is xslt 1.0.

Comment: If you really are using xslt 2 then it has [date formatting functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#format-date) built in.

Comment: @lan Roberts  Sorry ITs only xslt1.0

Comment: In which case the easiest approach will probably be to write an `<msxsl:script>` function using the .NET `DateTime` methods for parsing and formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Just Change the order

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
      xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <HTML>
  <HEAD>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY> 
   <xsl:for-each select="XMLSamples/FileDetails/Date">
      <DIV>
          Date Unedited:
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </DIV>
      <DIV>
          Date Edited:
          <xsl:value-of select="ms:format-date(., 'MMM dd, yyyy')"/>
      </DIV>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </BODY> 
  </HTML>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT**

Date Unedited: 2000-02-16T15:56:00

Date Edited: Feb 16, 2000